# Are $\| \Delta u \|_{L^p(\Bbb R^d)} + \| u \|_{L^p(\Bbb R^d)}$ and $\| u \|_{W^{2,p}(\Bbb R^d)}$ equivalent norms?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, unbounded-operators, semigroups-of-operators

> Is it true that  $$\| \Delta u \|_{L^p(\Bbb R^d)} + \| u \|_{L^p(\Bbb R^d)}\quad\text{and}\quad\| u \|_{W^{2,p}(\Bbb R^d)}$$ are equivalent norms?

This results is pretty easy and straightforward for $p=2$ using techniques via Fourier transform and Plancherel.
But what could we use in place of Fourier transform when $p\neq 2?$

Please prove or disprove or provide me with some good reference where I can fine.

I fact I need to show that the domain of the generator of the Gauss-Weierstrass semigroup in $L^p(\Bbb R^d)$ is $W^{2,p}(\Bbb R^d)$. This result is counterpart for the case $p=2$ where the domain of the generator is $W^{2,2}(\Bbb R^d)$.

Comment: This is well known. You can start, for instance, with the textbook of Gilbarg and Trudinger.

Comment: why a down vote here? is this question stupid?

Comment: The question is perfectly reasonable, but the timing is off. Let's say by seventy years or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the classical Calderón–Zygmund estimate gives
  $$\left\|D^2 u\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)}\leq C(p,d) \left\|\Delta u\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)}.$$
By interpolation, $\left\|u\right\|_{W^{2,p}(\mathbb{R})}$ is equivalent to 
  $$\left\|\Delta^2 u\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)}+\left\|u\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)}.$$
For detail proof you can look up Gilbarg-Trudinger Chapter 9 for $L^p$ estimate, and Adams for Sobolev spaces.

Comment: How do we manage the gradient terms?

Comment: In Adams' book Sobolev space, lemma 5.6 shows that the gradient term can be bounded by zero order and second order terms.